# Delete object via pointer

Tags: c#, pointers

I have a label array pointing to a label such as,

```
label_array[i] = a_label;
```

The array has global while label has function scope. Is it possible to delete label via array?

Comment: What do you mean by "delete" in this context. Remove from the form? (I assume by "label" you mean a visual label.)

Comment: Are you sure you tagged this right? C# and pointers are seldom mixed.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: With "delete" I mean remove totally.

Comment: "Remove totally" *from what*?

Comment: @EricLippert: Sorry, I am not familiar to C# too much. I mean to delete like in C++ or lets say from form.

Comment: label_array[i] = null;  You need to give more context to what label is

Comment: There's no need to "delete" like you do in C++. C# is an automatic-garbage-collection language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you can dispose of your objects just by setting their references to `null`, the garbage collector will take care of disposing of those objects for you. **However**, not all objects can be disposed just by setting their reference to `null`. In fact, all objects that implement `IDisposable` should be disposed by calling their `Dispose` method as it the case for GDI objects which require an explicit call to `Dispose` to free up their resources (see this link for [details](http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.com/2008/03/things-you-must-dispose.html))

This is being said, if `a_label` is a WinForms `Label` then you should do the following to dispose of it:

```
// REMOVE THE LABEL FROM THE PARENT CONTAINER FIRST 
// AND THEN DO THE FOLLOWING
label_array[i].Dispose();
label_array[i] = null;
```

**EDIT**
Just to highlight what @Groo mentioned in the comment below, make sure you remove your `Label` from the parent container before disposing of it, thanks @Groo!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this before label is removed from its parent control's `Controls` collection.

Comment: Please don't say "dispose of" when releasing a reference, in .NET, disposing of an object and releasing references (eventually making it eligible for collection) is not the same at all.